Windows Installer with CustomInstaller and Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the dll assembly
My solution has 3 projects with a project for CustomInstaller, a project for my WPF app and my Setup Installer.
After building my setup installer and running it, in the middle of the process I do have the error message:

Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the C:\Miopro\MS4\Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites.dll assembly. --> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Here is my Visual Studio 2022 Solution:

Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites

Class Library
.Net 7.0
Platform Target x86


Miopro.Suite.Wpf

WPF Windows Application
.Net 7.0
Platform Target x86


Miopro.Setup

Windows Installer Setup Project
Configuration Active (Debug)
Configuration Manager has al projects with Platform Any CPU
File System on Target Machine

Application Folder Default Location: C:[Manufacturer]\MS4
Application Folder

Primary output from Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites
Publish Items from Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites
Publish Items from Miopro.Suite.Wpf




Custom Actions

Install

Primary output from Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites







Environment:

Windows 11 (x64)

File System

Custom Action

CustomInstaller class
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class CustomInstaller : Installer
    {
        public CustomInstaller() : base()
        {
            this.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(CustomInstaller_Committed);
            this.Committing += new InstallEventHandler(CustomInstaller_Committing);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            WriteToEventLog("Install");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for 'Committing' event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void CustomInstaller_Committing(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToEventLog("Committing Event occurred.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for 'Committed' event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void CustomInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToEventLog("Committed Event occurred.");
        }

        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="savedState"></param>
        public override void Commit(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="savedState"></param>
        public override void Rollback(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Rollback(savedState);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="savedState"></param>
        public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }

        private static void WriteToEventLog(string message)
        {
            string source = "Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites.CustomInstaller";
            string log = "Application";

            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);
            }

            EventLog.WriteEntry(source, message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
    }
}

So, when I'm installing I can see my Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites.dll on my Application Folder Default Location, so it is available.

I already ready a few of the post over here, but none of them are talking about CustomInstaller on Custom Actions. What´s is the possible reason to get this error message?

System.Configuration.Install.dll DLL  is for .NET framework project.
So create .NET framework Miopro.Setup.Prerequisites
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installeventhandler?view=netframework-4.8.1&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(InstallEventHandler)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue#applies-to
